signInWithRedirect() without required attribute
I have a React app using AWS Amplify for user authentication. When I created the authentication structure for the app, I listed phone number as a required field.
Now, after creating a Google OAuth 2.0 client on their Cloud Console, I am trying to make Google SSO work on my app. Normally, you could simply add a <button> with onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({provider: "Google"})}, but because Google doesn’t intrinsically return a user’s phone number, the sign-in ultimately fails by stating that the phone number is a required attribute: error_description: attributes required: [phone_number].
Is there any workaround for this, or do I have to export my users to a new user pool where phone number is no longer required?
I tried adding the .../auth/user.phonenumbers.read scope to the Google sign-in screen, but Google is not passing this value back to my app. I believe this is because the user has to manually enable exposing their phone number in their Google account settings page.
